# Question regarding the meaning of bound variables in First Order Logic.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have two questions, which are probably easy explained but I am quite confused.

1- If I write:  *∀xDx → ∃xAx*, then the *x* in *∀xDx* and the *x* in *∃xAx* can be different things in an interpretation? Should they mean the same thing?

2- Is *∀yDy → ∃xAx* = *∀y∃x(Dy → Ax)* ?If it is, then what happens with *∀xDx → ∃xAx* = *∀x∃x(Dx → Ax)*? Wouldn't it be confusing?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) $\forall x Dx$ means "every thing is $D$". $\exists x Ax$ means "some thing is $A$". Thus, they do not "mean the same thing".

Comment: My question with the first one is whether the x could be a black cat and the x could be a Siamese dog (assume there are Siamese dogs). I understand that the same thing can have different predicates, my question is whether the same variable can be different "things" in the same sentence.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but then in question 2 the first example is correct and the second is not? Or neither of them are correct?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalences with nested quntifiers are a little bit tricky...

In general, we have that: $(\alpha \to \exists x \ \beta) \equiv \exists x \ (\alpha \to \beta)$, provided that $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$.

Thus, $(∀yDy \to ∃xAx) \equiv ∃x(∀yDy \to Ax)$, because $x$ is not free in $∀yDy$.

Nothing change if we write $∀xDx$.

But (alas!) we have that: $(\forall x \alpha \to \beta) \equiv \exists x \ (\alpha \to \beta)$, provided that $x$ is not *free* in $\beta$.

So, if we apply the rule to the formula above, what we get is:

> $(∀yDy \to ∃xAx) \equiv ∃x(∀yDy \to Ax) \equiv ∃x∃y(Dy \to Ax)$.

---

Finally, we have that: $(∀xDx \to ∃xAx) \equiv ∃x(Dx \to Ax)$.

Comment: Wow, any place where I can read further about this? My introductory book does not take such depth.

Comment: @César Dalí Vázquez Navarro - Many textbooks... Kleene, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA128) or Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf).

Comment: Grazie mille :)